# Write a Plugin in Python for audio

Tags: python, audio, plugins

I have written a script that on execution lets the user record a message by accessing their microphone and stores it.

I want to make this script useable over my website, which will require me to write a plug-in for the browser. Is there a good tutorial that will teach me how to write this plug in and set it up. is there another way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a browser plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

Comment: Do you want to have the user record a message on their computer and send it to you, or record what your microphone can hear? What (in non-programming terms) are you really trying to accomplish (i.e. "I want users to be able to leave me a recorded message")? Depending on what you want to do this may or may not be the best approach.

Comment: @Wayne: I mean, the user clicks a button on my website they can then can start recording an audio clip which gets saved to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely want to look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins

and

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

That were from the post Ignacio linked: [How to write a browser plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)