# How to realize communication between browser and backend?

Tags: browser, communication, backend, npapi, gecko

I have a backend software that needs to be able to communicate with a gecko-based web browser (and vice-versa). What is the best way to realize this? Since HTTP is rather one-way (with the exception of e.g. reverse AJAX which I consider to be quite "hacky") I am wondering how to do this.

Would creating an NPAPI-based plugin be an option? Based on the data exchanged between the browser and backend, the browser needs to manipulate the DOM of a webpage. The manipulations need to be quite dynamic and communication speed is an important requirement.

I am glad for any help pointing me in the right direction or providing useful resources that might be worth reading!

Comment: Why do you consider AJAX hacky? It really is the industry standard solution for this and is a quite mature technology.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean AJAX itself being hacky. You are right, AJAX itself is mature and impressive! I rather think solutions such as Comet or long polling as being a hack to create "duplex" communication over HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing browser plugins isn't quite trivial, if you can use alternatives like WebSockets (or their emulations like [web-socket-js](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736382/how-to-use-sockets-in-javascript-html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252829/what-browsers-support-html-5-websocket) for more details).

Only if such alternatives don't give you enough control because of special requirements should you consider writing a browser plugin.
With it you would get the full benefits of native code (high control over whatever API you choose) but also the problems that come with it:

- you have to start to worry about privileges
- bugs can crash the whole browser
- you might have to handle behavioral differences between platforms and browsers
- you have to worry about distribution on multiple platforms
- ...

If you need the higher level of control for some reason you could

- implement the connection handling of your choice in the plugin
- let the JavaScript initiate connections and send data
- let the JavaScript register handlers for incoming data etc.
- on incoming data call those handlers and pass them the data

To get started with NPAPI plugins [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin), to support IE too you'd have to write a [content extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28VS.85%29.aspx#content_extensions). Finally i would advise to take a look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) that already does much of the heavy lifting for you (hides the different APIs for IE and NPAPI, gives you a higher level API, fixes for browser bugs included, ...).