# How to write an application like skype as a Browser plugin?

Tags: plugins, npapi, skype, browser-plugin

What technology, frameworks, programming languages are involved? Must support for tcp inbound and outbound connections, read webcam and mic data.

Comment: try java (http://www.oracle.com/us/java/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser plugins have access to the operating systems native APIs, so there is no major difference to a stand-alone application regarding camera-, audio- and network-access. What you have to be aware of though is that your code might run in a less privileged process.

For Internet Explorer you will have to write [content extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically [ActiveX controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using C++. For all other browsers you will write [NPAPI plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin) C++ or C.

On Windows you can combine the two plugin types into one DLL. [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) does that, which you should look into as it already abstracts over the browsers (and other problems) for you.

Comment: NPAPI for gecko browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) for Internet Explorer 6,7,8,9 and 10 (with metro interface), how?

Comment: @Jose: Ah, i thought you only wanted to target NPAPI browsers. For Metro IE there is [no plugin support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/14/metro-style-browsing-and-plug-in-free-html5.aspx).

Comment: FireBreath is a great answer. I will check if it support listen connection on TCP and some workers to handle the connections.