# NPAPI tcp http server c++ in chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, npapi

Hello i was wondering how to get started in developing an NPAPI server with c++ in chrome. is this even possible? my goal is to have 2 clients find one another through the extension.thanks.

Comment: See also: [How to write a browser plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. You'll have to choose between using Firebreath, which can help you a lot by abstracting some of the NPAPI, or start from scratch and use colonel panic's tutorials.

- [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home)
- [Mozilla NPAPI documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference) (the most complete out there)
- [Colonel Panic tutorials](http://colonelpanic.net/category/plugindev/)

Be prepared to have some deep work to understand how plugins work!

Comment: Look particularly at FireBreaths' HTTPService library; it's mostly undocumented and not widely used, but it is a HTTP server that runs inside a FireBreath (and thus NPAPI) plugin.

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't know about Colonel Panic yet. Funny name too ;)