# Difference between Gecko Plug-in API and NPAPI

Tags: npapi, gecko

Can anyone tell me the difference between Gecko API Plugin development and NPAPI plugin development ?

And can anyone provide me with startup document on NPAPI plugin ?

Thanks in advance,
Akshay Sahu.

Comment: See [How to write a browser plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin) to get started.

Answer (score 3):

NPAPI is the plug-in API supported by Gecko, so there is no difference.

As for getting started, search this site for "NPAPI example" or "NPAPI documentation" and you'll get plenty of previous answers to that exact question.