# firefox plugin development in linux

Tags: c++, voip, npapi, browser-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a browser plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

I'm doing my master thesis, my topic is to develop a firefox plugin for MiniSIP application(its a open source VOIP application) on linux platform. Basically i need to use the sip stack of the MiniSIP source code for my devlopment. I need to develop a new firefox plugin based VOIP application along  with a new web-based GUI for the plugin. And the MiniSIP Source code was written in C++. Is there any good firefox plugin development tutorial available or any plugin development tool there to aided with my developemnt. I never developed a plugin before, so it would be helpful if someone suggest few ideas to progress with.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [mozilla plug in development page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins). [These tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins/External_resources_for_plugin_creation) might help you in your task.

You can also see [this reference page](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/) for details.

Comment: And in particular look at http://firebreath.org