# Create a plugin for WebKit browsers

Tags: java, c++, .net, webkit, browser-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a browser plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

I need to create plugin for all browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari using VS2010? How can i do that ?

if not possible using .NET then any-other way, using Java or C++ ?

For example, When we try to play flash file it gives us like 'Plugin missing...' Or Install flash Player...

i want to create something like this.

please help me how can i do that ?

Comment: Visual Studio is [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Do you mean .NET?

Comment: if not possible using .NET then any-other way ?

Comment: Please use your favorite search engine to look for "writing <browser> extension".  You will end up with links like http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/ and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html that will get you started.