# how make a simple plugin for several web browsers?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, plugins, web, browser-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a browser plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

A plugin in a modern web browser like firefox or chrome, allows execute files (use webcamera and other) and take more control of pc ( A plugin, not a extension).

How make a simple plugin for educational purposes ?

EDIT 1: Information of extension of chrome is extensive, but this question is not about of extensions (.xpi on firefox),otherwise plugins (.so or .dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) framework

Comment: not how make a extension, (.xpi) , is how make a plugin (.dll or .so)

Comment: my bad, check out this: http://firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home

Comment: FireBreath is good solution, please edit answer for accepted