# Is there any way to get the code of existing NPAPI plugins?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I want to develop my own NPAPI plugin - is there any way to get the code of existing plugins?
If not, what are the best practices / demos to start writing?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781180/168225) for getting started.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't look at code for most existing plugins, unless they are open source and you can find the source.  They are compiled and written in C or C++ generally.  I'd look at http://npapi.com/tutorial1 and http://www.firebreath.org

If you're beginning, FireBreath is probably the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Your NPAPI plugin may  have access to users filesystem
You  may read users profile folder and find existed plugins in the folder extensions.