# NPAPI plug-in call javascript function?

Tags: safari, npapi, browser-plugin

is there any way the NPAPI plug-in call the function in JS? if yes,please give me an example.By the way,my plug-in is running on safari.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call JS functions using [`NPN_Invoke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_Invoke) or [`NPN_InvokeDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_InvokeDefault).
I recommend to read through some [introductory material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin) on writing NPAPI plugins.