# How to create a Mozilla Firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have to create a Mozilla Firefox plugin that will help in taking remote access to other computer. I am actually a newbie to this and know nothing how to get it started. I tried googling it but all articles shows the creation of Firefox extension. Can anyone please guide me to some tutorial where it shows how to create a plugin for video or audio. Thanks in advance and please excuse my silly question.

Thanks

Comment: This a really broad question, and there's actually plenty of tutorials available online for creating npapi plugins...

Comment: @CViejo:Its really easy to comment. If there are many tutorial that describes how to create a firefox plugin, then why dont you share it instead of criticizing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a browser plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

Comment: Can you not make an addon out of it instead? I dont know if too many people here have the plugin dev expertise.

Comment: This is all the info you need on making a plugin this is the MDN official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Downloads
All the code I’ve created here is available both as a ZIP file of everything, so you can start experimenting, change stuff and see what happens. It is also available as an XPI file, which you can install in your Firefox just to test the functionality (drag and drop it into Firefox).

Download Link Target Finder code as a ZIP file.
http://www.robertnyman.com/extensions/LinkTargetFinder.zip

Download Link Target Finder as an XPI file.
http://www.robertnyman.com/extensions/LinkTargetFinder.xpi

Comment: Perhaps an example of what the code does might be helpful to the community as well, rather than just the links to the download :)

Comment: Thanks for the files. But, I wanted to know how to get it started. I mean how should I start in creating a plugin for Firefox.